# How to pull custom parameters to shipworks and display in orders grid

Tags: magento, oscommerce

I am using shipworks for shipping and pulling orders data from a shopping store.Now i want to pull a new order field which is not supported by shipworks xml.What could be the possible way to pull the unsupported order fields from shopping store and also display it on shipworks orders grid.
Any help

Comment: I have worked with Shipworks a bit with Magento and I suggest starting by editing the shipworks3.php connector in the site root.  I have found Shipworks support to be VERY helpful so it may be worth a call to them with this same question.

Answer (score 1):

We needed to add some custom information and shipworks was very helpfull and we got it done.
If you open up the shipworks3.php file you will see the following around line 760

```
// Uncomment the following lines to include a custom product attribute in the downloaded data.
        // These will appear as Order Item Attributes in ShipWorks.
        //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        //$productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
        //$product->load($productId);
        //$value = $product->getAttributeText("attribute_code_here");
        //if ($value)
        //{
        //     // write the gift message as an attribute
        //     writeStartTag("Attribute");
        //     writeElement("Name", "Attribute_title_here");
        //     writeelement("Value", $value);
        //     writeCloseTag("Attribute");
        //}
```

You can either use an attribute or tweak it for an order attribute.
If you let me know specifically what order details you're trying to import I can provide more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.interapptive.com/ShipWorksIntegrationGuide.pdf

Also some details at the very bottom of this page, http://www.shipworks.com/shipworks/help